# How to test void method in JUnit

Tags: java, junit

How to test void method using JUnit.

```
void add(int a, int b) {
 int c= a + b;
}
```

How to test above method by using Junit in Java.

Answer (score 15):

If a method has side effects, you can check them in your JUnit test.

In your example, the method has no side effects, so **there is nothing to test**.

If you still want to test it, you can use reflection to do so, but I don't think it is good practice.

You can check [JUnit FAQ](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#tests_4) related section:

> **How do I test a method that doesn't return anything?**
>
> Often if a method doesn't return a value, it will have some side effect. Actually, if it doesn't return a value AND doesn't have a side effect, it isn't doing anything.
>
> There may be a way to verify that the side effect actually occurred as expected. For example, consider the `add()` method in the `Collection` classes. There are ways of verifying that the side effect happened (i.e. the object was added). You can check the size and assert that it is what is expected:
>
> ```
> @Test
> public void testCollectionAdd() {
>     Collection collection = new ArrayList();
>     assertEquals(0, collection.size());
>     collection.add("itemA");
>     assertEquals(1, collection.size());
>     collection.add("itemB");
>     assertEquals(2, collection.size());
> }
> ```
>
> Another approach is to make use of [MockObjects](http://www.mockobjects.com/).
>
> A related issue is to design for testing. For example, if you have a method that is meant to output to a file, don't pass in a filename, or even a `FileWriter`. Instead, pass in a `Writer`. That way you can pass in a `StringWriter` to capture the output for testing purposes. Then you can add a method (e.g. `writeToFileNamed(String filename)`) to encapsulate the `FileWriter` creation.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a "big" method, you can extract do some Extract Method refactoring from it, to have several testable methods to test.

Or, as whoAmI said, you can test the side effects : database modification, file modification, ...

Answer (score -4):

Assume your class name is `Addition`,

```
@Test
public void testAdd(){
    Addition a = new Addition();
    assertEquals(a.add(2,3),5);
}
```

From [JUnit's FAQ](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#tests_4):

> Often if a method doesn't return a value, it will have some side effect. Actually, if it doesn't return a value AND doesn't have a side effect, it isn't doing anything.

Comment: The code given in this answer doesn't make sense. `a.add(2,3)` doesn't return anything, thus `assertEquals(a.add(2,3),5);` won't compile.